# Selenium webDriver : StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Получаю список нужных веб элементов `List<WebElement> temp = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.selection-link"));`
Далее я хочу достать из списка значения аттрибутов, пока я это делаю вываливается `StaleElementReferenceException`. Я так понимаю теряется связь с веб-элементами и выбрасывается это исключение.   **ВОПРОСЫ:**

1. Спарсенные веб-элементы я сохранил в листе, причем тут вообще webDriver? Я спарсил и положил в List, далее работаю с ним, какая связь у List в котором я сохранил то, что спарсил и у webDriver?
2. Как можно сохранить спарсенные веб элементы и работать с ними после `driver.quit`?
   В контексте моей задачи этот List в веб-элементами необходимо будет обработать несколько раз (например получить значения аттрибутов и содержимого тега)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebElement` не сохраняет `HTML` в памяти это просто ссылка к элементу в `DOM`.
Даже после сохранения элемента все функции выполняются через webDriver.
To-есть при вызове функции `WebElement#getAttribute` создается запрос к драйверу
чтобы "оттуда" найти атрибут.

Поэтому вы не можете ничего делать после того как обновили/закрыли/изменили страницу. (Уже сохранившие WebElement-ы просто не существуют)

Если хотите работать с данными после закрытии страницы можете использовать [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/)

Comment: К сожалению в задаче парсинга JSOUP тысячекратно медленнее Selenium, да и JS страницы через JSOUP не спрасишь.

Comment: Согласен. с jsoup-ом невозможно спарсить все. Если возможно поделитесь ссылкой посмотрю какие варианты есть.